# Delete rows with na in certain columns, only if dummy = 0

Tags: r

I want the following statement:

If df$dummy=0 --> delete all rows with na values in column 2:5.

I try

```
df[df$dummy==0] <- na.omit(df[2:5],)
```

But it does not function properly.

anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to include a little reproducible example, otherwise the folks here who answer your question will need to do it for you.

Suppose your data frame looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(dummy = c(0,  1,  1, 0, 0, 0,  1, 1, 0, 0),
                 col2  = c(1,  NA, 3, 4, 5, NA, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 col3  = c(1,  2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, NA),
                 col4  = c(NA, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, 10),
                 col5  = c(1,  2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, 10))
df
#>    dummy col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 1      0    1    1   NA    1
#> 2      1   NA    2    2    2
#> 3      1    3    3    3    3
#> 4      0    4    4    4    4
#> 5      0    5    5    5    5
#> 6      0   NA    6    6    6
#> 7      1    7    7    7    7
#> 8      1    8    8    8    8
#> 9      0    9    9    9    9
#> 10     0   10   NA   10   10
```

Then you can filter out the columns where `dummy == 0` AND where any row in columns 2:5 have `NA` by doing:

```
df[-which(df$dummy == 0 & apply(df[2:5], 1, anyNA)), ]
#>   dummy col2 col3 col4 col5
#> 2     1   NA    2    2    2
#> 3     1    3    3    3    3
#> 4     0    4    4    4    4
#> 5     0    5    5    5    5
#> 7     1    7    7    7    7
#> 8     1    8    8    8    8
#> 9     0    9    9    9    9
```

You will see that the only `NA` that remains occurs in a row where `dummy == 1`, as expected.

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  dummy = c(1,0,0,1,0),
  c1 = c(NA, NA, 2, 3, 1),
  c2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 4)
)
```

Solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(
    !(dummy == 0 & if_any(starts_with("c"), is.na)))
  dummy c1 c2
1     1 NA NA
2     1  3  1
3     0  1  4
```